# Language which can block mouse and keyboard input?

Tags: autostart

Is there a language which can block mouse and keyboard input from a specific device? Or only accept inputs from known (hard-coded in or available in a separate config file) devices?
I want it to disable the input from the device for the whole device.
Better yet, is there a program which already does this?

My specific situation is that classmates at school will randomly plug in wireless mouses and they will mess around and im left trying to save my work and shutdown before they accidentally delete something.

Answer (score 0):

This will heavily depends on your operating system.

For Linux, there is [USBGuard](https://usbguard.github.io/), you can whitelist the devices you allow and block everthing else.

Comment: hmm, im more specifically looking for a windows 10 program like this.